# batch command to backup folders and rename with timestamp doesn't works in XP power user permission

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, windows-xp, xcopy

I have formed a batch command script below but it doesn't work in Windows XP with Power User permission

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%

xcopy "D:\secure" "D:\secure_bak\bak - %stamp%" /i
```

I am getting an error as below

**Failed to register mof file(s).
Only the administrator group members can use WMIC.EXE.
Reason:Win32 Error: Access is denied**

Please suggest alternative for WMIC.EXE so I can also use this with Power User permission in XP.

Thank in advance for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script gives you reliable variables but using VBS in a batch file:

```
  :: date time using WSH/VBS
  :: datetime.bat V4.2
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  ::
  :: This uses Windows Scripting Host to set variables to
  :: the current date/time/day/day_number/week_of_year etc
  :: for Win9x/ME/NT/W2K/XP/Vista/Win7/Win8 etc
  :: Thanks go to Todd Vargo for his scripting
  ::
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  @echo off
  set TmpFile="%temp%.\tmp.vbs"
  echo> %TmpFile% n=Now
  echo>>%TmpFile% With WScript
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set m1="   + monthname(month(n), true)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set m2="   + monthname(month(n), false)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set woy="  + CStr(datepart("ww", n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set year=" + CStr(Year(n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set yr="   + Right(Year(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set month="+ Right(100+Month(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set day="  + Right(100+Day(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set hour=" + Right(100+Hour(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set min="  + Right(100+Minute(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set sec="  + Right(100+Second(n),2)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set dow="  + WeekDayName(Weekday(n),1)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set dow2=" + WeekDayName(Weekday(n))
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set iso="  + CStr(1 + Int(n-2) mod 7)
  echo>>%TmpFile% .Echo "set iso2=" + CStr(Weekday(n,2))
  echo>>%TmpFile% End With
  cscript //nologo "%temp%.\tmp.vbs" > "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  call "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  del  "%temp%.\tmp.bat"
  del  %TmpFile%
  set TmpFile=
  set stamp=%year%-%month%-%day%.%hour%_%min%_%sec%

  if not "%~1"=="" goto :EOF

  echo The year  is "%year%" or "%yr%"
  echo The month is "%month%" "%m1%" "%m2%"
  echo The day   is "%day%" "%dow%" "%dow2%"
  echo.
  echo ISO8601 Day-Of-Week number is "%iso%" and week of year is: "%woy%"

  echo.
  echo The time in hh:mm:ss is "%hour%:%min%:%sec%"
  echo The hour   is "%hour%"
  echo The minute is "%min%"
  echo The second is "%sec%"
  echo.

  echo The date and time stamp is "%stamp%"
  echo.
  echo date A yyyymmdd "%year%%month%%day%"
  echo date B mmddyyyy "%month%%day%%year%"
  echo date C ddmmyyyy "%day%%month%%year%"
  echo date D yymmdd   "%yr%%month%%day%"
  echo date E mmddyy   "%month%%day%%yr%"
  echo date F ddmmyy   "%day%%month%%yr%"
  pause
  :: datetime.bat
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no enough reputation for commenting, that's why I put an answer instead of commenting.

Addition to **Foxdrive**'s answer.

date/time extraction code is reusable, then I prefer to store such routines in separate files to be CALLed from other batches.

Also, recently I learned useful technics.

Here's a part of real batch I use under 2008r2:

```
for /f %%a in ('wmic path win32_localtime get minute /format:list ^| findstr "="') do (set %%a)
```

Well, it uses the prohibited WMIC, but I mentioned it for another reason. Note the **(set %%a)** part in extraction command. WMIC with **/format:list** returns the list of pairs like **minute=57** and we using these pairs as parameter to **set** command, making the WMIC's result the name of environment variable.
One can apply such technics to Foxdrive's method. One should create .vbs file producing similar list of variables he will get.

```
rem GetDateTime.vbs
rem Based on foxdrive//SE code
n=Now
With WScript
 .Echo "YYYY=" + CStr(Year(n))
 .Echo "MM="+ Right(100+Month(n),2)
 .Echo "DD="  + Right(100+Day(n),2)
 .Echo "HH=" + Right(100+Hour(n),2)
 .Echo "Min="  + Right(100+Minute(n),2)
 .Echo "Sec="  + Right(100+Second(n),2)
End With
```

Then, inside the main batch we using **for** operator (the path to .vbs's location may be required):

```
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo GetDateTime.vbs') do (set %%a)
```

That's all: after this **for** we'll have six variables set as we need.

P.S. Thanks again, foxdrive, for another hint: adding 100 to small numbers to add leading zeros when they're needed. I feel myself ashamed because I used prehistoric **ifs** like

```
if /i %month% lss 10 (
set mon1=0%month%
) else (
set mon1=%month%
)
```